# Rails before_filter not redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth

I am writing a Rails application that has a root_path for logging in and a profile path which users should be redirected to after login or if they are already logged in and visiting the homepage. I also want users that are not logged in to always be redirected to the login page, so I set up a before_filter to try and do that. Unfortunately, it doesn't catch anything. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

**Application Controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :require_login

  private
    def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end

    def require_login
      unless current_user
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    helper_method :current_user, :require_login
end
```

**Sessions Controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :require_login

  def index
    if current_user
      redirect_to profile_path
    end
  end

  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    puts(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to profile_path
  end

  def show
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
Fbapp::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: "sessions#index"

  match 'profile', to: 'sessions#show', as: 'profile', via: [:get, :post]
  match "auth/:provider/callback", to: "sessions#create", via: [:get, :post]
  match "auth/failure", to: redirect('/'), via: [:get, :post]
  match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout', via: [:get, :post]
  resources :posts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
 skip_before_filter :require_login
```

from `SessionsController`

Currently for all actions in SessionsController `skip_before_filter` removes the `require_login` filter from the before filter chain. Hence, it is never called.

BTW, You can control the actions to skip the filter for with the :only and :except options, just like when you apply the filters.

`skip_before_filter : require_login, :only => [:method_name]`

or

`skip_before_filter : require_login, :except => [:method_name]`

Comment: I added skip_before_filter :require_login, only: [:index, :create] to my sessions controller and that seemed to do the trick!